# Running jquery selections on a markup string that's not on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have markup that's returned from an ajax call. The markup isn't on the page yet. Before I put it on the page, I want to run jquery selections on it, for example to know the id of a certain div, etc.

Is it possible to run jquery selections on a string? I tried for example to do the following in an attempt to get the id of the div that has class myClass, but it's not working.

```
$(response).find('.myClass').attr('id')
```

Comment: Can you please post the value of `response`.

Comment: If you ever write `.attr('id')` in real code you should be deeply ashamed.

Comment: @sameold favour `[0].id`. One shouldn't mindlessly use the jQuery abstraction for everything and `.attr` should generally be avoided because it's a mess.

Comment: Impossible to know for sure without seeing the response you're getting, but if the `<div>` you want the ID of is a top-level element then `.find()` won't find it - you'll want to use `.filter()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that string is a HTML markup string like: `'<div><div class="myClass" id="sameold"></div></div>'` then you will get sameold as a value returned